# Hacer historigrama imprimiendo las veces que se repiten numeros en array

Tags: java

necesito hacer un historigrama en Java, el ejercicio es este:

El arreglo se llama myArray y contiene 10 elementos que corresponden a números enteros del 1 al 5. Un histograma representa que tanto un elemento aparece en un conjunto de datos. Por ejemplo, para el arreglo:

```
myArray:=(1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1)
```

el histograma se debe ver exactamente así:

```
1: ***** 
2: ** 
3: ** 
4: 
5: *
```

EL codigo que hice me imprime los elementos contados por asteriscos, pero el elemento que no existe no me lo imprime (4)

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int arr[] = new int[]{1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1}; 
    int n = arr.length; 


    boolean visited[] = new boolean[n]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        // Skip this element if already processed 
        if (visited[i] == true) 
            continue; 

        // Count frequency 
        int count = 1; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) { 
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) { 
                visited[j] = true; 
                count++; 

            } 
        } 
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " " ); 
             for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) { 
                  System.out.print('*');

             }
                  System.out.println();

    }
```

Como puedo hacer que aparezca el 4, o hacerlo correlativo??

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te pasa es que estás buscando la cantidad de veces que se repiten cada uno de los valores que contiene el arreglo. Si lo que quieres es determinar la cantidad de veces que se repiten los número del 1 al 5 deberías hacerlo así.

OJO: Fíjate en los comentarios que he puesto

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = new int[]{1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1}; 
        int n = arr.length; 

        boolean visited[] = new boolean[n]; 

        // Recorro de 1 a 5 para ver cuántas veces se repite cada valor
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
            // Cantidad de veces que se repite i
            int count = 0;// se inicia en 0 porque hasta ahora no hay coincidencias

            // Recorro el arreglo
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                // Skip this element if already processed 
                // Esto lo hago aquí adentro porque es donde recorro el arreglo ahora
                if (visited[j] == true)
                    continue;

                // Si el valor en esa posición es el analizado (i) incremento
                if (arr[j] == i) {
                    visited[j] = true; 
                    count++;
                } 
            } 

            // La i tiene el valor y count las veces que se repite
            System.out.print(i + ": " );
            for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) { 
                System.out.print('*');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias E. Betanzos, exactamente es como dices, yo habia pensado eso de contar cuantas veces se repite cada valor, pero no sabia como contarlos y a la vez recorrer de x a y los valores buscando los vacios, ya que el arreglo puede ser dinamico, y no se me ocurrio esa solucion donde mapeaste los valores del mas pequeño al mas grande de la lista. Esa es la solucion que necesitaba :D. Muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

ES mejor usar un HasMap

```
int myArray[] = new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1};

public static void main (String args[]) {
   HashMap<Integer, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
  hash.put(5, "");
  hash.put(4, "");
  hash.put(3, "");
  hash.put(2, "");
  hash.put(1, "");
  
  for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    hash.put(new Integer(myArray[i]), hash.get(myArray[i])+"*");
  }
  
  for(Integer key: hash.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key+": "+ hash.get(key));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solo quería dejar una optimización al algoritmo propuesto utilizando la clase Array para un ordenamiento y hacer mas flexible la búsqueda en el array ya que se puede ingresar cualquier valor dentro del array y este buscara he imprimirá los números dentro del rango del uno a el numero maximo :

```
int arr[] = new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1};

    //1: Ordenamos el array
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    //2: Obtenemos el ultimo item del array que seria el valor maximo.
    int max = arr[arr.length - 1];

    //3: recorremos todos los numeros entre 1 y el valox maximo, para imprimirlos.
    for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
        // 4: imprimimos el numero a contar
        System.out.print(i + ": ");
        //5: recorremos el array para imprimir * por cada vez que encontremos el numero actual i
        for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
            // 6: si el numero actual i es igual al numero en la pocision x del array imprime *
            if (i == arr[x]){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        //7: salto de linea al final de imprimir los * o vacio en caso de no encontrar el número
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ya es algo tarde pero encontré una solución con una menor cantidad de lineas de código:

```
    static int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1 };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int aux = 0;
        string[] myHistograma = new string[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            aux =   myArray.Count(c => c == (i+1));
            myHistograma[i] = new string('*', aux);
             Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + myHistograma[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente alguien por aquí (como yo) esté buscando hacerlo en C#. Aquí está mi implementación. Utilicé de referencia las demás respuestas para realizar la mía, se optimizaron muchas cosas, inclusive la impresión en consola.

```
public static void Main()
{
  //Your code here
  string[] histograma = new string[5];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    int count = myArray.Count(c => c == (i + 1));
    histograma[i] = new string('*', count);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {histograma[i]}");
  }
}
```

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta es correcta, esta mal en esta pregunta... la pregunta es sobre java... y tu respuesta perdida en el medio sobre C#... nadie la va a buscar aca... igual, yo te diria que no optimizaste la impresion en consola.. es mas... la hiciste mas lenta.. para que usas hitograma???? en este contexto, no tiene sentido... que es myArray??? este codigo ni siquiera compila...